# IDEA запуск кода | ошибка Error: Main method not found in class com.company.Main

Tags: java

Как запустить данный код? Должен выводить сортировку, ругается на отсутствие main(String[] args), и выдает ошибку

> Error: Main method not found in class com.company.Main, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application.

Можете помочь запустить код?

```
package com.company;
import java.util.List;
public class Main {

    public static void sort(List<Integer> list) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int element : list) {
            if (element < min)
                min = element;
            if (element > max)
                max = element;
        }
        int[] buckets = new int[max - min + 1];
        for (int element : list)
            buckets[element - min]++;
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
            for (int j = buckets[i]; j > 0; j--)
                list.set(arrayIndex++, i + min);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ну чтобы запустить ваше приложение, вам нужна стартовая точка "место" откуда программа начнет исполняться и им по умолчанию считается как раз вот этот метод: public static void **main**(String[] args)

а уже из него вы можете запустить метод sort(List list)... только для этого в метод sort нужно будет передать какой то список List целых чисел, что указано в параметрах метода

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(2);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(6);

        System.out.println("несортированный список " + list);

        List list2 = sort(list);

        System.out.println("сортированный список " + list2);

    }
    public static List<Integer> sort(List<Integer> list) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int element : list) {
            if (element < min)
                min = element;
            if (element > max)
                max = element;
        }
        int[] buckets = new int[max - min + 1];
        for (int element : list)
            buckets[element - min]++;
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
            for (int j = buckets[i]; j > 0; j--)
                list.set(arrayIndex++, i + min);

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, а как вызвать в нем метод sort(List) и передать список из условно 5 элементов? Можете кодом подсказать?

Comment: добавил код, только и его мало... отсортированный список еще нужно получить обратно или не получать а распечатать... добавил в метод сортировки еще System.out.println(list), чтобы вы в консоли увидели результат работы метода

Comment: изменил код. сам метод сортировки теперь возвращает отсортированные значения обратно в main, после чего их можно например распечатать

Comment: на вход (метода) приходят не сортированные данные, после чего они сортируются и присваиваются той же переменной, но если хотите, то можете присвоить их другой переменной List list2 = sort(list); В этом случае list продолжает ссылаться на не сортированные данные, а list2 уже на сортированный список

Comment: двусвязный список вместо new ArrayList<>() напишите new LinkedList<>();

Comment: обновил код в ответе

Comment: @VBugaenko это уже классика, `psvm not found`, каждую неделю вижу такой вопрос.

Comment: Извини, я не решаю учебные задания, и это противоречит правилам сообщества SO  ... ты можешь попробовать задать новый вопрос о конкретной проблеме, которая у тебя вызывает затруднение с вариантом собственного решения... и даже если не я, то другой точно ответит